# transform an existing angular app in ionic

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I encounter a problem with an angular app that I want to migrate in ionic

I used ui-router for angular and here is my app.js(taken here : https://github.com/tarlepp/angular-sailsjs-boilerplate-frontend/blob/master/src/app/app.js ). I haven't made any changes on this file for my project

Now I want to reuse this file for my project so I replace app.js given by ionic by this one and added

```
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
// Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
// for form inputs)
if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
  cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
}
if(window.StatusBar) {
  StatusBar.styleDefault();
}});
```

inside app.run

here's my index.html :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
<title></title>

<link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
<link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
-->

<!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>

<!-- your app's js -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="frontend">
<ion-pane>
  <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
    <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content>
  </ion-content>
</ion-pane>
</body>
</html>
```

I just replace the name of ng-app by frontend and ionic theme isn't charged properly.

I don't know if the problem comes from ui-retour dependencies or something else? I think I'm missing something

Note: I know that I will have to change my html and css files for the project , but for index.html I just have what is provided by ionic and I don't have the ionic tab with 'ionic blank starter' as if I begin a blank ionic project

here's my router changed :

```
enter code here
(function() {
'use strict';



 angular.module('frontend', [
'ionic',
'frontend-templates',
'frontend.core',
'frontend.myportfolio',
'frontend.mysocial',
'frontend.myleads',
'frontend.admin'
  ]);

 angular.module('frontend')
 .config([
  '$stateProvider', '$locationProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',      '$httpProvider', '$sailsSocketProvider',
  '$tooltipProvider', 'cfpLoadingBarProvider',
  'toastrConfig',
  'AccessLevels',
  function config(
    $stateProvider, $locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider,   $httpProvider, $sailsSocketProvider,
    $tooltipProvider, cfpLoadingBarProvider,
    toastrConfig,
    AccessLevels
  ) {



    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;

    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];

    // Add interceptors for $httpProvider and $sailsSocketProvider
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('AuthInterceptor');
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('ErrorInterceptor');

    // Iterate $httpProvider interceptors and add those to $sailsSocketProvider
    angular.forEach($httpProvider.interceptors, function iterator(interceptor) {
      $sailsSocketProvider.interceptors.push(interceptor);
    });

    // Set tooltip options
    $tooltipProvider.options({
      appendToBody: true
    });

    // Disable spinner from cfpLoadingBar
    cfpLoadingBarProvider.includeSpinner = false;
    cfpLoadingBarProvider.latencyThreshold = 200;

    // Extend default toastr configuration with application specified configuration
    angular.extend(
      toastrConfig,
      {
        allowHtml: true,
        closeButton: true,
        extendedTimeOut: 3000
      }
    );

    // Yeah we wanna to use HTML5 urls!
    $locationProvider
      .html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
      })
      .hashPrefix('!')
    ;

    // Routes that needs authenticated user
    $stateProvider
      .state('profile', {
        abstract: true,
        template: '<ui-view/>',
        data: {
          access: AccessLevels.user
        }
      })



    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/myportfolio/mydatabase');
    }
   ])
   ;


 angular.module('frontend')
   .run([
     '$rootScope', '$state', '$injector','$ionicPlatform',
     'editableOptions',
  'AuthService',
  function run(
    $rootScope, $state, $injector,$ionicPlatform,
    editableOptions,
    AuthService
  ) {

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function   stateChangeStart(event, toState) {
      if (toState.url=='/login' || toState.url=='/register' ) {
        $rootScope.myStyle = {'background-color':'#333'}
        $rootScope.headerIsloaded = false;
        $rootScope.sidebarIsloaded = false;

      }else{

        $rootScope.myStyle = {};
        $rootScope.headerIsloaded = true;
        $rootScope.sidebarIsloaded = true

      };

      if (!AuthService.authorize(toState.data.access)) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(toState.data.access)

        $state.go('auth.login');
      }
    });

    // Check for state change errors.
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function stateChangeError(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
      event.preventDefault();

      $injector.get('MessageService')
        .error('Error loading the page');

      $state.get('error').error = {
        event: event,
        toState: toState,
        toParams: toParams,
        fromState: fromState,
        fromParams: fromParams,
        error: error
      };

      return $state.go('error');
    });


    //bout de code ionic

    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form inputs)
      if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      }
      if(window.StatusBar) {
        StatusBar.styleDefault();
      }
    });

  }
])
 ;
  }());
```

Comment: please provide me with your router

Comment: I edited my question to add my router

Comment: Even when I use only ionic   in 'frontend' dependencies that don't solve my problem

Comment: You need to be more specific. What type of error are you getting? Is only visual or you have something wrong showing in the console? You should check that first.

Comment: it's only visual : like as I said, the problem is that it seems that my router isn't working because the main page for the staret project in ionic isn't displayed properly . llok my note :" Note: I know that I will have to change my html and css files for the project , but for index.html I just have what is provided by ionic and I don't have the ionic tab with 'ionic blank starter' as if I begin a blank ionic project"

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you missing the markup for ui.router to inject your state views into?

```
<ion-view view-title="your-view">
</ion-view>
```

if you create a new app with

```
ionic start myApp
```

it defaults to the `tab` template which includes the following body in it's index.html

```
  <body ng-app="starter">
    <!--
      The nav bar that will be updated as we navigate between views.
    -->
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <!--
      The views will be rendered in the <ion-nav-view> directive below
      Templates are in the /templates folder (but you could also
      have templates inline in this html file if you'd like).
    -->
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
```

here the `ion-nav-view` is what allows ui.router to insert its views

Comment: I'm working on the home page when you start a new project , so no

Comment: if you look at the markup on the index.html, there is no view for ui.router to fill. the directive [ion-content](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionContent/) is not play view ui.router.